# EF core inserts new record instead of updating

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have searched related questions but couldn't find a solution. I have an asp.net core web app, where I select a row and edit the record. It shows the form in a popup window with the related data, the ID too (which is hidden). This is the entity:

```
public class Sender
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string  Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

I use the repository pattern to handle data operations:

```
public class DataSender : IRepositorySender
{
    private DataContext DataContext;
    public DataSender(DataContext Context)
    {
        DataContext = Context;
    }
    public IEnumerable<Sender> Senders => DataContext.Senders;
    public Sender GetSender(long SenderId)
    {
        return DataContext.Senders.Find(SenderId);
    }
    public void AddSender(Sender Sender)
    {
        DataContext.Senders.Add(Sender);
        DataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void UpdateSender(Sender Sender)
    {
        DataContext.Senders.Update(Sender);
        DataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void DeleteSender(Sender Sender)
    {

    }
}
```

And this is the related action:

```
[Route("{SenderId}")]
    public IActionResult UpdateSender(long SenderId)
    {
        ViewBag.Mode = "update";
        return PartialView("Sender", SenderRepository.GetSender(SenderId));
    }
    [HttpPost("UpdateSender")]
    public IActionResult UpdateSender(Sender Sender)
    {
        SenderRepository.UpdateSender(Sender);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(List));
    }
```

I get the desired data in the popup, save the changes, but EF inserts a new record instead of updating it. Why?

**EDIT:**

This is the update view:

```html
@model Sender

<form asp-action=@(ViewBag.Mode == "new" ? "AddSender" : "UpdateSender") asp-controller="Sender"  method="post">
    @using (Html.DevExtreme().ValidationGroup())
    {
        @(Html.DevExtreme().Form<Sender>()
            .ID("form")
            .ColCount(1)
            .Items(items => {
            items.AddSimpleFor(m => Model.Id).Visible(false);
            items.AddSimpleFor(m => Model.Name);
            items.AddSimpleFor(m => Model.Address);
            items.AddSimpleFor(m => Model.ContactPerson);
            items.AddSimpleFor(m => Model.ContactEmail);
            items.AddGroup().Items(groupItem => groupItem.AddSimple().Template(
                @<text>
                    <div style="text-align: right">
                        @(Html.DevExtreme().Button().ID("save").Text("Mentés").Width(100).Type(ButtonType.Success).UseSubmitBehavior(true))
                        @(Html.DevExtreme().Button().ID("cancel").Text("Mégsem").Width(100).Type(ButtonType.Normal).OnClick("close_onClick"))
                    </div>

                </text>));
            })
            .LabelLocation(FormLabelLocation.Top)
            .FormData(Model)
        )
    }
</form>
```

[image: Id field is valid]

**EDIT 2:**
This is the output of the debug window. Is it useful to you? I see, that EF requires a new Id and insert the record in the database. The key point is, that why the Id is 0, why EF or the webapp (model binding) don't recognize, that the entity has already a valid Id value.

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking: Debug: 'DataContext' generated temporary value '-9223372036854774805' for the 'Id' property of new 'Sender' entity.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking: Debug: Context 'DataContext' started tracking 'Sender' entity with key '{Id: -9223372036854774805}'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking: Debug: DetectChanges starting for 'DataContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking: Debug: DetectChanges completed for 'DataContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction: Debug: Beginning transaction with isolation level 'Unspecified'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction: Debug: Began transaction with isolation level 'ReadCommitted'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Debug: Creating DbCommand for 'ExecuteReader'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Debug: Created DbCommand for 'ExecuteReader' (3ms).
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Debug: Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@p0='Teszt cím' (Nullable = false) (Size = 4000), @p1='teszt@teszt.com' (Nullable = false) (Size = 4000), @p2='Teszt név' (Nullable = false) (Size = 4000), @p3='Teszt cég' (Nullable = false) (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [Senders] ([Address], [ContactEmail], [ContactPerson], [Name])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3);
SELECT [Id]
FROM [Senders]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = scope_identity();
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking: Debug: Foreign key property 'Sender.Id' detected as changed from '-9223372036854774805' to '71' for entity with key '{Id: 71}'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Debug: A data reader was disposed.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction: Debug: Committing transaction.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction: Debug: Committing transaction.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction: Debug: Disposing transaction.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking: Debug: The 'Sender' entity with key '{Id: 71}' tracked by 'DataContext' changed from 'Added' to 'Unchanged'.
```

Comment: EF will not insert if the Id value is already there, you will get Cannot insert explicit value for identity column exception, or  you have enabled identity insert in SQL

Comment: I don't want to insert, I would like to update. How is this comment related to the question?

Comment: Entity framework will see Id field if it 0 then it will insert else it will update

Comment: As I wrote, I have the corresponding Id to the record in a hidden field. I changed the update method in the way, that I now assign each field the new value and I see now, that the Id is 0. But why? In the popup form, I see the correct Id value.

Comment: share your view and controller action, debug and check if you are receiving id value at your Controller Action

Comment: I edited the post and added the view (the controller actions were already added). I checked, that I get the corresponding Id too.

Answer (score 0):

I see it, cant help without seeing the complete flow, you could try using Debug Logger and see change tracking

```html
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options
              .UseLoggerFactory(MyLoggerFactory)
              .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")).EnableSensitiveDataLogging());
              
              
              
               public static readonly ILoggerFactory MyLoggerFactory
            = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .AddFilter((category, level) =>
                        (category == DbLoggerCategory.ChangeTracking.Name |
                         category == DbLoggerCategory.Database.Transaction.Name |
                         category == DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name)
                         && level == LogLevel.Debug)
                    .AddDebug();
            });
```

This will produce debug log with Change Tracking, Transaction and Command issued by Entityframework Core along with Data Passed, Watch out particularly changetracking as this will identify if your object is being added or updated

**Edit1**
Debug: 'DataContext' generated temporary value '-9223372036854774805' for the 'Id' property of new

I see Id does not have value, between your controller and savechanges some where it is getting removed, are you using any type of mapping, or check your repository, put a debug using f11 and see where it is getting lost

Comment: I edited the post with the output from the debug window.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that the visibility of the Id field was set to false and this caused the default value 0 resp. not binding the Id field. I added a `@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Id)` field and now it works as expected.